# HTML input pattern for an email domain

Tags: regex, html, input, pattern-matching

I tried to use the **pattern** attribute of the HTML **input** tag to do a simple client-side validation for a specific email domain using the following code:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@domain\.com\.ph$" />
```

I expected the following input to succeed:
**test.test@domain.com.ph**

But somehow it does not seem to work. 
Am I using an incorrect **regex**?

To eliminate some answers, I have tried checking the following:

- browser supports pattern validation
- the pattern `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@domain.com.ph$`
- the pattern `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@domain.com.ph`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove anchors `^` and `$`. Those are not required when using `pattern`.

And `0-9A-Za-z_` in character class can be replaced by `\w`.

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[\w.%+-]+@domain\.com\.ph" />
```

Comment: stackoverflow won't let me make this an edit as it is not long enough, but in case anyone tries this in the future, the `-` in the character class has to be escaped in order to make it work. i.e. it needs to be `[\w.%+\-]+@domain\.com\.ph`